# Flutter create a file and write its contents

Tags: flutter, path, provider, createfile

I am working on an app which gathers text content from server and as the next step I am trying to save them into separate files to be saved with in apps storage. Storage is a folder called 'storage'. Inside storage, there is a '**fileList.txt**' file which contains the list of files.

In **pubspec.yaml** I declared this folder in the assets as follows:

```
 assets:
- storage/
```

And I can read it using the following function:

```
Future<String> readFileContent() async {
    String response;
    response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('storage/fileList.txt');
    return response;
  }
```

To save the file I made use of online examples which use '**path_provider**' package. However when I try to save one of the downloaded files for instance '**file4.dat**' using the following functions, I encounter the following error. How can I resolve that problem?

```
  saveFileLocally() async {
    await _writeFile();
  }
  
  Future<Null> _writeFile() async {
    await (await _getLocalFile()).writeAsString(vars.fileContents);
  }

  Future<File> _getLocalFile() async {
    // get the path to the document directory.
    String dir = (await PathProvider.getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
    print('DIR :::: ' + dir);
    return new File(
        '$dir/storage/files/file' + vars.newFileID.toString() + '.dat');
  }
```

The error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, 
path = '/data/user/0/com.example.ferenova_flutter_app/files/storage/file4.dat'
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Thanks guys and take care !!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While checking out `path_provider` examples, I ran into this important detail:

```
Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
        : await getApplicationSupportDirectory(); //FOR iOS
```

This solved my problem. I am no longer using default `rootBundle` asset to process any external files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your paths.

storage/fileList.txt is not the same as $dir/storage/files/file' + vars.loadedFileID.toString() + '.dat'

you should try:

```
response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('$dir/storage/files/file' + vars.loadedFileID.toString() + '.dat'');
```

Or something similar.
GL

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer:) I think there has been a misunderstanding. Those two files are different files. One is ".txt" and the other is a ".dat" file. I need to create the ".dat" file and creation is an issue. rootBundle is used to read and it is working without any problem.

Comment: Ok then... Are you sure that the path you are using actually exists in your device?

From this link:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-io/File/File.html

My guess is that you harcoded a Path you want your files to be in but this path does not exist.

try $dir+ vars.newFileID.toString() + '.dat'

Maybe this exactly does not work but thats my idea. GL

Comment: I have no idea :D I am using a library that is referred in many tutorials and I am following the suggested technique. Even the code I used is a copy from the tutorials.

Comment: can you paste that library?/ post the full code for testing

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I used “path_provider”  library.