# how to load flutter asset files if rootBundle.load freezes without throwing an error?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, assetbundle

I'm trying to update an old flutter package to Android v2 embedding. However running the example just freezes on loading an asset using **rootBundle.load**  [line 153](https://github.com/rix133/flutter_sphinx/blob/d28aa1a169c59148a44e249b232e95d66e96b130/lib/flutter_sphinx.dart#L153) *(tested on Windows 10, android studio 2021.1.1, android emulators API 29,30,31)*  no error or anything.

the fork itself is here: https://github.com/rix133/flutter_sphinx/

Can anybody suggest a better way of loading the asset files or point to me what I'm doing wrong in V2?

My guess is, that it was working under Android v1 embedding.

Comment: Yey! I got an error `F/crash_dump32(18517): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 179:` **Permission denied**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491219/flutter-create-a-file-and-write-its-contents might be a solution

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96046 possibly due to deferred loading